# Как получить координаты границы `Layout` в пикселях (px)

Tags: java, android

Двигаю `ImageView` с помощью `ImageView.animate().translationX(x).translationY(y)`
до границы `Activity` (или `Layout`) одним словом  до границ экрана. Как найти координаты этих границ? (в `px` - я так понимаю `translationX` только в них понимает) 
Пробовал так но это размеры всего экрана и `ImageView` уходит дальше чем нужно.

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    X = size.x;
    Y = size.y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо найти/получить `Layout` внутри которого расположен ваш `ImageView`. Например через `ImageView.getParent()` - правда если есть вложенные `Layout` - ответ будет не всегда корректным. Лучше сразу взять поименованный `Layout` через `findViewById()`. Дальше все просто:

```
width=layout.getWidth(); //ширина в пикселях
height=layout.getHeight(); //высота в пикселях
```

Только замерять надо после отработки метода `onMeasure()`, иначе они будут нулевые.

Comment: Угу так тоже пытался и как раз получал нулевые значения. А можно узнать по подробнее о методе onMeasure() - почему то не могу найти внятной документации с его описанием...